# Static ip routes not persisting after a reboot on Debian Wheezy

Tags: networking, debian-wheezy, static-ip

I am trying to set up the Ethernet address with a public IP address given by my ISP. However, the default gateway is on a different subnet than the IP address. This is unusual but perfectly acceptable. I just have to set up manual routes like this to make it work:

`ip route add a.b.c.d/32 dev eth0`

`ip route add default via a.b.c.d`

And it works!

However I want it to survive a reboot. My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this -

`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address a.b.c.d
netmask 255.255.255.255
post-up ip route add w.x.y.z/32 dev eth0
post-up ip route add default via w.x.y.z`

If I bring the interface down and back up again, or if I reboot, the static routes don't persist.

Comment: Do you mean to use post-up, or just up?

Comment: I frankly don't know the difference. I am just using samples I found online.